# Data classes in interface

Tags: java, kotlin

In `Kotlin` I can write like this:

```
interface KeyMapperService {
interface Add {
    data class Success(val key: String, val link: String): Add
    data class AlreadyExist(val key: String): Add
}

interface Get {
    data class Link(val link: String): Get
    data class NotFound(val key: String): Get
}

    fun add(key: String, link: String): Add

    fun getLink(key: String): Get
}
```

How will this code look like in Java? I can not understand.

Comment: IntelliJ has a Kotlin decompiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a direct translation of the Kotlin file into Java:

```html
interface KeyMapperService {
    interface Add {
         class Success implements Add {
            Success(String key, String link){}
        }

        class AlreadyExist implements Add {
             AlreadyExist(String key){}
        }
    }

    interface Get {
        class Link implements Get{
            Link(String link){}
        }

        class NotFound implements Get{
            NotFound(String key){}
        }
    }

    public Add add(String key, String link);

    public Get getLink(String key);
}
```